# Improve network stability throughout house

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I am having trouble maintaining a stable wireless connection in the basement of my house. Our router is on the first floor of the house (Comcast modem/router combination). I am getting around 2/5 bars of signal in the basement, but that is all that is needed usually. There are many devices connected to the same wireless network.

There are 6 people living in the house. When I am the only one using the connection, the connection is stable. When we are all using the connection, the connection is very unstable and drops for me sometimes or is extremely slow. What is the best course of action? I don't think I need an extender or repeated because I am able to get a connection in the basement. The problem is not one person using all the bandwidth either (or maybe it is?.

I think it is because of the simultaneous network traffic overwhelming the router.

Answer (score 0):

It's a probable software issue. here's the things you can check:

- take a look at [here](http://gizmodo.com/5936365/five-free-ways-to-boost-your-wi-fi-signal) and consider the precautions.
- some routers have a feature called **[Smart Beam](http://www.amazon.com/what-is-smart-beam/forum/Fx1Y3THD2DLLV0O/Tx1Y0ZDHDZ50HMN/1?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00CCIL9NU)**. it actually 
  focuses signal on a single client to improve its functionality.
- Make sure if **[QoS](http://searchunifiedcommunications.techtarget.com/definition/QoS-Quality-of-Service)** is turned off in your router. it'll prioritize bandwidth for connected clients.

hope it works :)